# add event on every ajax.beforeSend() and complete()

Tags: jquery, ajax, version

I need to check version of application in every **ajax request**.
I did something like this:

```
$(function() {
var version;

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(event, xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Version', version);
        console.log(version);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        var localVer = xhr.getResponseHeader('Version');

        console.log(localVer);
        if( typeof version === "undefined" ){
            version = localVer;
        } else if( version !== localVer ){

            var r = confirm("Version has been changed.");
            if (r == true) {
                location.reload(true);
            }
        }
    }
  });
});
```

but this methods are overwritten by calling **ajax.beforeSend** and complete when I'm sending the requests.
like:

```
beforeSend: function() {
                loader();
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

`beforeSend:` doesn't queue. As you have observed, a specific `beforeSend:` will override a `beforeSend:` established by `$.ajaxSetup()` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9ajwgq7/).

You can do something like this :

```
function setRequestHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Version', version);
    console.log(version);
}

$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        setRequestHeader(xhr);
        loader();
    }
});
```

But it's probably as easy to do this :

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Version', version);
        loader();
    }
});
```

Or incorporate `xhr.setRequestHeader('Version', version)` in your `loader` function and allow `xhr` to be passed :

```
function loader (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Version', version);
    ...
}

$.ajax({
    beforeSend: loader
});
```

Comment: problem is that I have nearly 50 .ajax requests. Is there any way to add this function, not touching every request?

Comment: Not as far as I can see, no.